How to merge 2 partitions (without data loss)
I installed Fedora on a 37 GB drive which is a bit too small; I have 104 GB free space, and I want to merge with it without losing data. I have no idea how to do this; I tried using gparted and resize it to a bigger size, but that did not work. Luckily they are next to each other.
~
❯ lsblk
NAME        MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINTS
sda           8:0    1  29.3G  0 disk 
├─sda1        8:1    1  29.3G  0 part /run/media/cinnamon/Ventoy
└─sda2        8:2    1    32M  0 part 
zram0       252:0    0     7G  0 disk [SWAP]
nvme0n1     259:0    0 238.5G  0 disk 
├─nvme0n1p1 259:1    0   512M  0 part /boot/efi
├─nvme0n1p2 259:2    0 106.2G  0 part 
└─nvme0n1p3 259:3    0  34.6G  0 part / # Fedora



You must move the free space  AFTER the partition. And then extend the partition

Ah thank you, how do i do that im still new to managing linux partitions... @RomeoNinov

You have to merge without using it, so have you tried with live usb?

Yes @maxemilian

@MuslimGamerrr, boot from live CD/USB and use GParted for example

@RomeoNinov already tried that...

And what happened? You have to tell us everything as we aren't with you

i could rezise it larger, it just gave a error, ill try again and take note of the error

now i cant rezise it anymore

You can do it as you intended because you allocated as free-space next of a part of a gpt partition. There is a common gpart live usb for this. Maybe you try with this and share the error for more accurate approach.

thanks, ill try it

IT WORKED THANKS

Just make sure the partitions you want 2 merge are next eachother, then boot https://gparted.org/liveusb.php and resize the part you want bigger, thanks @maxemillian
